# Get Contents of <td> in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the contents of a specific `<td>` tag in a document.  Currently my code looks like this

For row in rows:

```
 data = row.findAll('td')
  for col in data:
      if col.string == 'Address':
         address = col.findNext('td')
         print address
```

The print address on console reveals this:

```
<td> 
Victoria Park Ave & McNicoll Ave, Toronto, ON M1W 3Y3, Canada
<br /> <a class="viewmap-link" href="/c-ViewMap?AdId=299616106">View map</a> 
</td>
```

I'm trying to get everything before that `<br/>` tag in the "address"   I tried `address.string` but it is returning "None".

Comment: Please try to remember to accept answers to your questions by clicking the check mark next to the best one. You've asked 12 questions and only done that for two; most of your questions probably have good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Tag.getText() method

```
data = row.findAll('td')
  for col in data:
    if col.string == 'Address':
      address = col.findNext('td')
      print address.getText()
```

Edit: that gets all the text, not just before the `<br>`. Try try this instead

```
data = row.findAll('td')
  for col in data:
    if col.string == 'Address':
      address = col.findNext('td')
      print address.contents[0]
```